# Slider breaks before loading

Tags: jquery-slider

Hi I am running WordPress latest version with a custom coded jQuery featured post slider in all pages. My problem is that the slides appears broken for 2 seconds when the page is loading, after the page is fully loaded it runs fine. If you wish you can have a look  http://crunchmarketing.com.au/. Please help me out.

Comment: do you use: 

`$(function() {
  $( "#slider" ).slider();
});`

to initiate the slider by anychance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're using this (or similar) to execute the code:

```
$(function() { 
  $( "#slider" ).slider(); 
});
```

This is the same as:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $("#slider").slider();
})
```

meaning the code wont execute until the page has loaded. It's the same with all jquery's functions, they are only loaded when the document has loaded completely.